# DuplicateKeyException: on BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have used `setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ")`, it was working before now this doesnt seem to work. I tried everything but not able solve this error. Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.extract.SpringBatchPocApplication.main(SpringBatchPocApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; [SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified. Cause . . . . . :   A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N exists over one or more columns of table tableName in LibraryName. The operation cannot be performed because one or more values would have produced a duplicate key in the unique index or constraint. Recovery  . . . :   Change the statement so that duplicate keys are not produced.  For information on what rows contain the duplicate key values, look at the previously listed messages in the job log (DSPJOBLOG command) or press F10 (Display messages in job log) on this display.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: [SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified. Cause . . . . . :   A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N exists over one or more columns of table file in library. The operation cannot be performed because one or more values would have produced a duplicate key in the unique index or constraint. Recovery  . . . :   Change the statement so that duplicate keys are not produced.  For information on what rows contain the duplicate key values, look at the previously listed messages in the job log (DSPJOBLOG command) or press F10 (Display messages in job log) on this display.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:243) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:922) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:160) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:150) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: [SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified. Cause . . . . . :   A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N exists over one or more columns of table FIle in Library. The operation cannot be performed because one or more values would have produced a duplicate key in the unique index or constraint. Recovery  . . . :   Change the statement so that duplicate keys are not produced.  For information on what rows contain the duplicate key values, look at the previously listed messages in the job log (DSPJOBLOG command) or press F10 (Display messages in job log) on this display.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:903) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.7.jar:JTOpen 9.7]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:742) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.7.jar:JTOpen 9.7]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonExecute(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1075) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.7.jar:JTOpen 9.7]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.executeUpdate(AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java:1861) ~[jt400-jdk8-9.7.jar:JTOpen 9.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:867) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table you have marked one of the column as unique and that same value is repeating hence it is throwing error

Case 1: Try removing unique key (if not necessary) from column and run

Case 2: Rectify your data for the column which is marked unique

Comment: These are Spring related Repository, cannot change the structure. Although i did resolve this. But now I am getting new error.                                                                                     
 A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.output.ansi.enabled=always}. If you want to run this job again, change the parameters